# Could you *PLEASE* ban this creep?

Tags: support, spam, ban

This guy here keeps coming back every couple of days and keep SPAMMING Stackoverflow:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5056691/spam-removed

Please just **BAN** this guy to the moon and free us from having to deal with this creep over and over again - thanks!

I'm talking about this guy here:   https://stackoverflow.com/users/625176/amit-singh

Comment: In future, you can flag the post for moderator attention to make this type of comment. The moderators will then deal with him.

Comment: @marcog: I've been doing this since the first time he showed up - and I've suggested this to the moderators several times - so far, no reaction - thus my post here....

Comment: @marc_s Is he posting under the same profile or is he creating new accounts?

Comment: @marcog: I had been under the impression it was the same profile - at least for a while. But now this one here seems to be brand-new - same name and same user icon to it... But our whizkids at Stackoverflow should be able to pinpoint this creep and based on IP and name be able to keep this freak out, I hope!!

Comment: @marc_s The account has been deleted. But unless there's an IP ban, he'll just evade it. I hate these idiots. :-/

Comment: @marcog: he always posts as "Amit Singh", he always uses "Google" as his single tag - that should be enough to just blow him away if he comes around again, no??

Comment: @marc_s As soon as SO would ban either of these markers he would use something else... An IP ban would/could be most effective

Comment: @Henk: Unless he is using dynamic IP (per session).

Comment: A dynamic IP is highly likely anyway; lots of places charge extra for a static address. Better is to tag his account so that anything he submits gets automatically deleted *but not showed as such to him*. That'll destroy his effectiveness without tipping him off.

Comment: If I see this same account come back I'll start making note of the IP addresses and send them along to the team. IP bans are reserved for very special cases iirc, (like a flat out spam bot attack, or other organized disruption). Complaining directly to the ISP might be the next logical step, but that's usually futile.

Comment: Just a note: an IP ban will be futile since he's got Dynamic IP ( Please do not block the entire IP range - that IP block belongs to one of India's largest ISP's and loads will be banned - including me). Also, he *creates* a new email id for every account, every day - the email id format is `mondd_yy@yahoo.com`. I'm not sure how this user can be banned. (yes, I've been tracking this account everyday for the past 2-3 weeks on SU)

Comment: @Tim, another one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5114019/google-cosmos-express-99-sector-99-gurgaon-call-for-conform-booking-9899299961

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What kind of spam?

If it is the same URL let us know and we can add that URL to our blacklist.

Comment: he creates a new email id for every account, every day - the email id format is `mondd_yy@yahoo.com`. I'm not sure how this user can be banned.

Comment: @sathya is there any other common string?

Comment: unfortunately no

Comment: @Sathya I have an idea. Create email accounts for days _in the future_. For example. Today is July 28. Make `aug01_13`, `aug02_13`, etc.